# extract result from curl

Tags: php, curl

The code below echoes the result, but how do I extract the balance from the result for input into db?

```
extract($_POST)
$url="http://sms.bbnplace.com/bulksms/acctbals.php?username=xxx@yahoo.com&password=xxxpass";
//}
$fields = array(
        );


//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
//}                 
//execute post

$result = curl_exec($ch);




//if ($result == '1801') { echo " is the SMS Credit Balance";} else { echo "Oooops, balance not seen";}
//close connection

curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get the result correctly, then all this cUrl stuff isn't relevant at all. You actual question is how to parse a string, but you didn't show us the string to parse, nor the attempts you made. Can you please rewrite your question?

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```